# How to determine wattage of a resistor I found

Tags: resistors, resistance, watts

In general is there a way to know what the wattage rating of a resistor is?  I have a large bin of resistors of varying resistances and physical sizes.  I assume size correlates to wattage as a larger resistor would be able to dissipate more heat.

How would I go about determining what a safe wattage is to pass through a resistor?

Comment: 1/8 watt carbon resistors are about 3/8" long x 1/16" diam. 
1/4 watt carbons are about 3/8" long x 1/8" diam 
1/2 watt carbons are about 1/2" long x 1/4" diam 
1 watt carbons are about 3/4" long x 1/4 " diam 
2 watt carbons are about 11/16" long x 5/16" diam